# Error showing while gradle building

Tags: android

I am getting following error while building the gradle:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in the dependency of the `project-level build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your buildScript's dependency in your root build.gradle file like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" } 
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Apply plugin in app module's build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these dependencies for the **project build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

and put this at the end of the **app-level build.gradle** file (after the dependencies).

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```